# Laravel3 how to send variable into controller from view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel 3 at the moment, and I have a technical question. I have a list of authors and I'm trying to make some links to set a filter to order those authors.

I tried setting a default parameters to order by Name, it works, but I can't pass any other filters.

This is my route :

```
Route::get('authors', array('as'=>'authors', 'uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

And this is my controller function :

```
public function get_index($filter="name"){
    return View::make('authors.index')
        ->with('title', 'Authors list')
        ->with('authors', Author::order_by($filter)->get());
}
```

And this is the links in my view trying to send the filter I want

```
{{ HTML::link_to_route('authors', 'Id', array('id')) }}
{{ HTML::link_to_route('authors', 'Name', array('name')) }}
```

The parameters I try to send (id and name) from the view never reach the controller so it always use default parameter.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting any route parameters, you must do something like:

```
Route::get('authors/(:any?)', array('as'=>'authors', 'uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

Take a look at the docs: http://three.laravel.com/docs/routing#wildcards